# Getting smallest amount among all options

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Could any one refer to a known algorithm that could do the following, without the need to brute force for all options on the table;
The table has columns: id, quantity, source and date of creation
a user enters a set of id's, and the algorithm should return the smallest quantity amongst all sources for the LAST row (based on the date of creation)

Example:

```
(id) 1 On June 1st quantity was 9 from Source A
2 On June 1st quantity was 5 from Source A
3 On June 1st quantity was 7 from Source A
1 On May 25th quantity was 6 from Source B
2 On May 25th quantity was 9 from Source B
3 On May 25th quantity was 10 from Source B
3 On May 1st quantity was 7 from Source A
1 On May 1st quantity was 6 from Source B
```

Assuming a user entered a set contaning id's 1 and 2, the latest quantity from source A respectively for id's 1 and 2 are 9 and 5, and from source B 6 and 9, since A has the total less than all other sources, the result should be A(9)

What I have done and trying to achieve a better solution:
For every source, loop all products entered and get the sum, and then get the min for all sources
Hoping I explained the matter correctly, could anyone suggest an algorithm or fastest way to solve the above problem?

Answer (score 0):

Preprocess your data, to make it more convenient. Create a dictionary keyed by tuples of the form (id,source) whose values are the most recent quantity for that combo. You will have to do some looping to set up such a dictionary, after which you will have very fast sums where all you have to do is sum over the values corresponding to the ids in the target subset. In a language like Python with good support for dictionaries, this would be fairly easy.

If you have this data stored in something like an R or pandas dataframe, there will be solutions which are more appropriate for those tools. If this is the case, you could ask a properly tagged question which containing a reproducible sample dataframe.